# media queries are not working in chrome(desktop) but working in firefox

Tags: css

I am working on media queries and these are not working in chrome but working in firefox.How to make them work in chrome?
here is my css code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: they are not working ? --> you mean what ? what color you don't see ?

Comment: as a side note you will never see the green

Comment: eventhough i minimize the screen only yellow color is applying to the body

Comment: it's working fine for me on chrome, i see yellow and red

Comment: why,could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: reason of what ? why it's working ?

Comment: ok,thanks for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
  // your css here
}
```